# Spring Cloud SQS consumption blocking until all messages processed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

We're using [Spring Cloud AWS](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/) to interact with SQS. We use the `@SqsListener` annotation to pull messages off our queues. We have `deletionPolicy = NEVER`, which means we manually acknowledge all messages we pick off.

Our problem is that the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (which handles the processing of messages from a queue) waits for all worker threads to finish before picking further messages off the queue.

In other words, what we're seeing is this:

- Pull 10 messages off a queue.
- Start 10 threads to do work.
- One of the threads doing work gets blocked on a slow IO call.
- The application is now blocked from fetching more messages off the queue, and is as such blocked from doing more work at all, until that slow call finishes.

We can see the code in `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.AsynchronousMessageListener` which is responsible for this

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isQueueRunning()) {
        try {
            ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = getAmazonSqs().receiveMessage(this.queueAttributes.getReceiveMessageRequest());
            CountDownLatch messageBatchLatch = new CountDownLatch(receiveMessageResult.getMessages().size());
            for (Message message : receiveMessageResult.getMessages()) {
                if (isQueueRunning()) {
                    MessageExecutor messageExecutor = new MessageExecutor(this.logicalQueueName, message, this.queueAttributes);
                    getTaskExecutor().execute(new SignalExecutingRunnable(messageBatchLatch, messageExecutor));
                } else {
                    messageBatchLatch.countDown();
                }
            }
            try {
                messageBatchLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().warn("An Exception occurred while polling queue '{}'. The failing operation will be " +
                    "retried in {} milliseconds", this.logicalQueueName, getBackOffTime(), e);
            try {
                //noinspection BusyWait
                Thread.sleep(getBackOffTime());
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, we'd like for the message listener to continually pick messages off the queue for processing.

We can't seem to implement our own `MessageListenerContainer` since the `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` is package local.

Is there any way around this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What is holding the message polling thread is the `messageBatchLatch.await()` statement. It seems that just removing the latch would do it. Something like:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isQueueRunning()) {
        try {
            ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = getAmazonSqs().receiveMessage(this.queueAttributes.getReceiveMessageRequest());
            for (Message message : receiveMessageResult.getMessages()) {
                if (isQueueRunning()) {
                    MessageExecutor messageExecutor = new MessageExecutor(this.logicalQueueName, message, this.queueAttributes);
                    getTaskExecutor().execute(new SignalExecutingRunnable(messageExecutor));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().warn("An Exception occurred while polling queue '{}'. The failing operation will be " +
                    "retried in {} milliseconds", this.logicalQueueName, getBackOffTime(), e);
            try {
                //noinspection BusyWait
                Thread.sleep(getBackOffTime());
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will work if your `TaskExecutor` implementation:
- Has a fixed-size thread pool
- Blocks when `execute` function gets called and no threads are available.

This is how most of implementations work but it is worth checking yours.

Comment: Thanks, but how would we actually override the ``AsynchronousMessageListener``? It's private..

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that this wasn't your code :-(... Well, in that case and assuming spring doesn't allow you to override that behavior, I guess it will be easier to implement your own queue-polling code...

Comment: You could override `startQueue(String queueName, QueueAttributes queueAttributes)`, right?